# Linq ForEach() not populating fields

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm having trouble trying to calculate 3 fields on my model using `ForEach()` and linq.  The query returns "activities" for a specific issue.  One of those fields is "TimeSpent", which is a `long`.  It's basically the time spent on that item in milliseconds.  I'm trying to show Days, Hours, and Minutes based on this "TimeSpent" field, for each activity. Here's the Model:

```
public class ActivityGridModel
{
    public DateTime ActivityDate { get; set; }
    public string ActivityType { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public string EnteredBy { get; set; }
    public long TimeSpent { get; set; }
    public int Days { get; set; }
    public int Hours { get; set; }
    public int Minutes { get; set; }
}
```

This is the query that I built:

```
var activities = from a in Session.Context.Activities
                  join at in Session.Context.ActivityTypes
                    on a.ActivityTypeID equals at.ActivityTypeID
                  join u in Session.Context.Users
                    on a.CreatedByUserID equals u.UserID
                  where a.IssueID == issueId
                  select new ActivityGridModel()
                  {
                      ActivityDate = a.ActivityDate,
                      ActivityType = at.ActivityType1,
                      Notes = a.Notes,
                      EnteredBy = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName,
                      TimeSpent = a.TimeSpent
                  };
```

And here's where I try to populate the Days, Hours, and Minutes of my model:

```
activities.ToList().ForEach(a =>
{
    TimeSpan timeSpent = new TimeSpan(a.TimeSpent);
    a.Days = timeSpent.Days;
    a.Hours = timeSpent.Hours;
    a.Minutes = timeSpent.Minutes;
});

return activities.ToList();
```

I get all the other fields in the results but Days, Hours, and Minutes are all 0.  I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong in every sense. Days, Hours and Minutes have to be read only properties that calculate their value from TimeSpent internally. The way you've implemented this you can end up with invalid data in your objet. For exapmle:

```
var model = new ActivityGridModel { TimeSpent = X };
model.Days = 5;
model.Hours = 10;
```

Is this valid ?

A better approach would be computing Days, Hours and Minutes internally:

```
public class ActivityGridModel
{
    public DateTime ActivityDate { get; set; }
    public string ActivityType { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public string EnteredBy { get; set; }
    private long _timeSpent;
    public long TimeSpent
    { 
       get
       {
          return _timeSpent;
       } 
       set 
       {
          _timeSpent = value;
          var tsSpent = new TimeSpan(_timeSpent);
          Days = tsSpent .Days;
          Hours = tsSpent .Hours;
          Minutes = tsSpent .Minutes;
       }
    }
    public int Days { get; private set; //readonly for class clients }
    public int Hours { get; private set; //readonly for class clients}
    public int Minutes { get; private set; //readonly for class clients}
}
```

Comment: While @Selman22 answer works and is correct, I decided to use this solution instead because brz is right, those fields should be calculated internally.

Answer (score 2):

First store the list into a variable then use `Foreach`

```
var activityList = activities.ToList();
activityList.ForEach(a =>
{
    TimeSpan timeSpent = new TimeSpan(a.TimeSpent);
    a.Days = timeSpent.Days;
    a.Hours = timeSpent.Hours;
    a.Minutes = timeSpent.Minutes;
});
return activityList;
```

You are first executing the query (with `.ToList()`), using `ForEach` on the created list but then you are throwing away that list.

Then you are executing the same query again and returning the result as list without any modification which makes `ForEach` pointless.

Linq queries are lazily evaluated. So you will get a new list each time you execute the query.

The important thing here is that the `ForEach` doesn't return the list, it changes it. So you have to put the list into a variable, make the changes then return the modified list.

Comment: It would be worth explaining *why* this is required.

Comment: Yup, that's definitely better.

Comment: He's asking for a chainsaw to cut a piece of cake and you're giving it to him with your answer instead of guiding him in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

@Selman22 has the solution, but this is why the code didn't work.

The original assignment to activities appears as it might be `IQueryable<ActivityGridModel>`, and thus executing `.ToList()` on it twice effectively creates two sets of data.  The first list is updated, and then like @Selman22 said it is thrown away.  The second list is the a fresh set of data that is not updated.

In addition to the redundant creation this looks like it would execute an enumeration twice on the context, which could be potentially expensive as well.  Keep in mind that you should reduce the number of calls to methods which can be expensive.  It may look like there is not a lot executing, but there could be an abstraction layer that reads/writes data from disk, a database or a web service.

Here is a repeat of what @Selman22 said about the solution:

```
var activityList = activities.ToList();
activityList.ForEach(a =>
{
    TimeSpan timeSpent = new TimeSpan(a.TimeSpent);
    a.Days = timeSpent.Days;
    a.Hours = timeSpent.Hours;
    a.Minutes = timeSpent.Minutes;
});
return activityList;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var activities = from a in Session.Context.Activities
              join at in Session.Context.ActivityTypes
                on a.ActivityTypeID equals at.ActivityTypeID
              join u in Session.Context.Users
                on a.CreatedByUserID equals u.UserID
              where a.IssueID == issueId
              select new ActivityGridModel()
              {
                  ActivityDate = a.ActivityDate,
                  ActivityType = at.ActivityType1,
                  Notes = a.Notes,
                  EnteredBy = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName,
                  TimeSpent = a.TimeSpent,
                  Days = a.TimeSpent.Days,
                  Hours = a.TimeSpent.Hours,
                  Minutes = a.TimeSpent.Minutes
              };
```

Comment: This isn't doing the same thing as what the OP's code is doing, and you couldn't make it do what the OP's code is doing like this because the DB won't be able to translate this into SQL.